# Cordova won't build anymore

Tags: android, cordova, compilation

I don' t understand, I have nothing changed or updated for several days, and yesterday the compilation work, and now here is this:

```
fred@fred:~/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute$ export PATH=${PATH}:"/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk/tools" && export PATH=${PATH}:"/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools"
fred@fred:~/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute$ cordova build android && cordova prepare android && cordova compile android
Running command: /home/fred/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute/platforms/android/cordova/build 
Buildfile: /home/fred/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: RatouFut
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for RatouFut...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for RatouFut...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...

BUILD FAILED
/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/fred/appli/android-studio/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:659: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
    at com.android.ant.MultiFilesTask.processFiles(MultiFilesTask.java:89)
    at com.android.ant.AidlExecTask.execute(AidlExecTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:221)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 2 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/fred/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /home/fred/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
fred@fred:~/public_html/tests/appli/ratoufute$
```

what can i do ? i change nothing in config, no update for cordova or plugins or java....

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Delete the folders 'ant-build' and 'ant-gen' should solve your problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but this solution didnt solve my issue. I didnt change any config/build files either. I just edited the project slightly and the following errors came out:
/Developer/adt-bundle/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/adt-bundle/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Developer/adt-bundle/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Answer (score 2):

Even add and removal of platform fixes the issue:
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android