# Cordova/Phonegap Android Emulator Build Error

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'm using Cordova 3.4.0,

When I try and run:

```
cordova emulate android
```

I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/danny/Documents/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/danny/Documents/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:950: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
    at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependencyTask.java:87)
    at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 2 seconds

/Users/danny/Documents/Apps/washbox/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/danny/Documents/Apps/washbox/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/danny/Documents/Apps/washbox/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Everything was previously working, but when I changed my www folder, I got this error. Even when I reverted back to the dummy files phonegap/cordova give you I still get the same error?

Does anybody have a clue as to what could be causing this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The answer here helped me: [Cordova won't build anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583119/cordova-wont-build-anymore)

> Delete the folders 'ant-build' and 'ant-gen' should solve your
>   problem.

So e.g.

```
find . -name ant-build -o -name ant-gen | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when I changed files in `www` directory. You shall first build the project, then run :

```
cordova build android
```

and then run :

```
cordova run android
```

I hope this helps.