# cordova run android unexpectedly not working, apparently related to build.xml and aidl

Tags: android, cordova, ant, build.xml

This is unexplainable to me.

One minute I'm changing HTML in my cordova app and the next minute `cordova run android` fails with the below error code.

It makes no sense because I never installed anything and I haven't touched the build.xml file so how could it fail? How do I fix this or even go about investigating what happened?

It's saying the error is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error on line 659. When I check line 659 of the build xml it is referring to `aidl`.  I don't even know what `aidl` is...I've including that section of the build xml as well.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated...

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:659: java.lang.Arr
ayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
    at com.android.ant.MultiFilesTask.processFiles(MultiFilesTask.java:89)
    at com.android.ant.AidlExecTask.execute(AidlExecTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 5 seconds
Error: C:\Users\Terence\Documents\Code\IceBreaker\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: 
Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Terence\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

Relevant section of build.xml

```
652        <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode
653                elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java">
654             <echo level="info">Handling aidl files...</echo>
655             <aidl executable="${aidl}"
656                    framework="${project.target.framework.aidl}"
657                    libraryBinAidlFolderPathRefid="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
658                    genFolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
659                    aidlOutFolder="${out.aidl.absolute.dir}">
660                 <source path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
661             </aidl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.

Found the answer here:

[Cordova won't build anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583119/cordova-wont-build-anymore?rq=1)

The answer is to delete the `ant-build` and `ant-gen` folders in platforms\android

Doesn't explain it or suggest it has anything related to anything but it worked. wtf...