# Rebuilding cordova project causes errors with build.xml

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I've been following the [cordova guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) on setting up the hello world project. Everything works as it should up until I make a change and try to run `cordova emulate` again. I'm using the android emulator for this example.

I've tried to remove the android platform from the hello world project and rebuild but it does not make a difference.

I've also tried deleting the ant-build and ant-gen from the platform android in the hello world app after see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583119/cordova-wont-build-anymore) but still get the same error.

My os is windows 8.

I get the following errors

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while execu
ting this line:
C:\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
: 1
at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.j
ava:180)
    at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
    at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependenc
yTask.java:87)
    at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 4 seconds

C:\Apache24\htdocs\bapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Apache24\htdocs\b
app\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: C:\Apache24\htdocs\bapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command fail
ed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\danny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out different suggestions from other posts made some updates. I updated my jdk to version 8, then I uninstalled the build tools for android 20,21 leaving me with the build tools for android-19. This solved the problem.